# Mapping a function with vnoremap

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, neovim

I'm trying to set up a function in Neovim that can manipulate a visual block of text and bind it to a key. I've copied this one out of the [`function-range-example` documentation](https://neovim.io/doc/user/eval.html):

```
function! Cont() range
  execute (a:firstline + 1) . "," . a:lastline . 's/^/\t\\ '
endfunction

vnoremap <silent> S :set opfunc=Cont<CR>
```

If I call the function with `:'<,'>call Cont()`, everything works fine. However, when I highlight a selection of text in visual block mode, I get this error:

```
E481: No range allowed
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You could pass the visual  range as: `call Cont(line("'<"),line("'>"))` and the function declaration should then be `function! Cont(start_line, end_line)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mapping doesn't make much sense. It sets an operator function that is never used.

`E481` is thrown because doing `:set` from a `vmap` leads to `:'<,'>set...`, but the `:set` command doesn't take a range.

Use this instead:

```
vnoremap <silent> S :call Cont()<cr>
```